# Correct conversion of substr to substring

Tags: javascript

I have found some old piece of code [here](https://krazydad.com/tutorials/makecolors.php) to generate a color pallet. This includes the following function:

```
function byte2Hex(n)
  {
    var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F,1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F,1);
  }
```

I thought thats an easy one because I just need to replace substr by substring but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`String.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)? The second argument has different meaning. For `substr()` it represents the number of characters to extract but for `substring()` it represents the index of the first character after the substring to extract. Basically, `s.substr(a, b)` is the same as `s.substring(a, a+b)`.

Comment: Yes I read but I didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for `substr` or `substring` if you're only trying to get a single character from the string. You can just use indexed access:

```js
function byte2hex(n) {
    const nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    const first = (n >> 4) & 0x0f;
    const second = n & 0x0f;
    return nybHexString[first] + nybHexString[second];
}

console.log(byte2hex(255));
```

Answer (score 8):

Both [`String.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) accept two arguments and while the first argument has the same semantic (the index of the first character to extract), the second argument has different meaning.

For `substr()` it represents the number of characters to extract but for `substring()` it represents the index of the first character after the substring to extract. Basically, `s.substr(a, b)` is the same as `s.substring(a, a+b)`.

Your code becomes:

```js
function byte2Hex(n)
{
  const nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  const s1 = (n >> 4) & 0x0F;
  const s2 = n & 0x0F;

  return nybHexString.substring(s1, s1 + 1) + nybHexString.substring(s2, s2 + 1);
}
```

Read the documentation of [`String.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).